# Conversion of String to the Field data type in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, json, object

I have an JSON which changes dynamically with respect to the Fields in the field set.

For example, sometimes JSON can look like:

```
{
  'Name': 'SFdev',
  'IsGenuine__c': 'True',
  'No_Of_Active__c: '3'
}
```

Sometimes, JSON can look like:

```
{
  'Coupon_code__c': '12345',
  'IsActive__c': 'True',
  'Name': 'SFdev'
}
```

When I send this to apex, I want them to Typecast from `**String**` to the appropriate data type. Assuming that I know the data type (as the key of JSON is the field API name), how do i convert to the appropriate data type from String type dynamically? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the correct data types, you don't need to type cast.

```
{
  'Name': 'SFdev',
  'IsGenuine__c': true,
  'No_Of_Active__c: 3
}
```

Or:

```
{
  'Coupon_code__c': '12345',
  'IsActive__c': true,
  'Name': 'SFdev'
}
```

You can then immediately deserialize into an sObject:

```
sObject record = (sObject)JSON.deserialize(sourceJson, Account.class);
```

---

If you want to do so explicitly, then you end up with some really complicated code:

```
String sobjectName = 'Account'; // You need to know this
Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(sourceJson);
sObject record = ((sObject)Type.forName('Schema',sobjectName).newInstance());
Map<String, sObjectField> fields = record.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(String fieldName: values.keySet()) {
  Object value = values.get(fieldName);
  DescribeFieldResult fieldInfo = fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
  switch on (fieldInfo.getType()) {
    when id, address, combobox, email, encryptedstring, multipicklist, phone, picklist, reference, string, textarea, url {
      record.put(fieldName, (string)value);
    }
    when Boolean {
      record.put(fieldName, Boolean.valueOf((String)value));
    }
    when Date {
      record.put(fieldName, Date.valueOf((String)value));
    }
    when DateTime {
      record.put(fieldName, DateTime.valueOf((String)value));
    }
    when currency, double, percent {
      record.put(fieldName, Double.valueOf((String)value));
    }
    when integer {
      record.put(fieldName, Integer.valueOf((String)value));
    }
    when long {
      record.put(fieldName, Long.valueOf((String)value));
    }
  }
}
```

This also doesn't handle all data types (see [DisplayType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm)) but handles the most common data types. I would strongly advise that you just fix your JSON and avoid the headache of maintaining this code, if at all possible.